# Unique validation of two fields from different tables in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have three models related in Yii2, with attributes:

**AyudanteSituacionLaboral (ID, FechaInicio, State, Ayudante_ID)**

**Ayudante(ID, Name )**

**HRutaDistribucion (ID, Fecha, Ayudante_ID)**

I need to check uniqueness of **Fecha and Ayudante_ID** against **AyudanteSituacionLaboral=>FechaInicio** and **AyudanteSituacionLaboral=>Ayudante_ID** respectively. So when I choose from HRutaDistribucion form an Ayudante instance that already has an entry in AyudanteSituacionLaboral with Fecha like FechaInicio field, it launches an error message.
Here's HRutaDistribucion Model:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use backend\controllers\AyudanteSituacionLaboralController;
use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "hruta_distribucion".
 *
 * @property integer $HRuta_ID
 * @property integer $Carro_DistribucionCarroID
 * @property integer $ChoferChofer_ID
 * @property integer $AyudanteAyudante_ID
 * @property integer $HojaRuta
 * @property string $Fecha
 * @property string $FechaEmision
 * @property integer $Capacidad_Transportada
 *
 * @property Ayudante $ayudanteAyudante
 * @property CarroDistribucion $carroDistribucionCarro
 * @property Chofer $choferChofer
 * @property ViajeDistribucion[] $viajeDistribucions
 */
class HrutaDistribucion extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'hruta_distribucion';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           // [[ 'HojaRuta', 'Fecha', 'FechaEmision'], 'required'],

            [['Fecha', 'FechaEmision','Carro_DistribucionCarroID', 'ChoferChofer_ID', 'AyudanteAyudante_ID', 'HojaRuta','Capacidad_Transportada'], 'safe', 'on'=>'search'],
            ['Fecha', 'unique', 'message' => ("Este trabajador ya esta en esta fecha")]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'HRuta_ID' => 'Hruta  ID',
            'Carro_DistribucionCarroID' => 'Carro  Distribucion Carro ID',
            'ChoferChofer_ID' => 'Chofer Chofer  ID',
            'AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Ayudante Ayudante  ID',
            'HojaRuta' => 'Hoja Ruta',
            'Fecha' => 'Fecha',
            'FechaEmision' => 'Fecha Emision',
            'Capacidad_Transportada' => 'Capacidad  Transportada',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAyudanteAyudante()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ayudante::className(), ['Ayudante_ID' => 'AyudanteAyudante_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCarroDistribucionCarro()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CarroDistribucion::className(), ['CarroDistID' => 'Carro_DistribucionCarroID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getChoferChofer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Chofer::className(), ['Chofer_ID' => 'ChoferChofer_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getViajeDistribucions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ViajeDistribucion::className(), ['HRuta_DistribucionHRuta_ID' => 'HRuta_ID']);
    }


}
```

Here's AyudanteSituacionLaboral Model:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "ayudante_situacion_laboral".
 *
 * @property integer $AyudanteAyudante_ID
 * @property integer $Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID
 * @property string $Fecha
 * @property integer $Cant_Dias
 * @property integer $Cant_Horas
 * @property string $Descripcion
 * @property string $Fecha_Creacion
 *
 * @property Ayudante $ayudanteAyudante
 * @property SituacionLaboral $situacionLaboralSitL
 */
class AyudanteSituacionLaboral extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'ayudante_situacion_laboral';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['AyudanteAyudante_ID', 'Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID', 'Fecha_Creacion'], 'required'],

            [['AyudanteAyudante_ID', 'Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID','FechaInicio','FechaFin', 'Fecha_Creacion','Cant_Horas'], 'safe'],
            [['Descripcion'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['Cant_Horas', 'required', 'when'=>function($model){
                    return (empty($model->FechaInicio))? true:false;
                }, 'whenClient'=>"function(){
                    if ( $('#FechaInicio').val()=== undefined)
                    { false;
                    }else{
                    true;}
                }" ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Nombre Ayudante',
            'Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID' => 'Situación Laboral',
            'FechaInicio' => 'Fecha Inicio',
            'FechaFin' => 'Fecha Fin',

            'Cant_Horas' => 'Cant. Horas',
            'Descripcion' => 'Observ.',
            'Fecha_Creacion' => 'Fecha  Creacion',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAyudanteAyudante()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ayudante::className(), ['Ayudante_ID' => 'AyudanteAyudante_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSituacionLaboralSitL()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SituacionLaboral::className(), ['SitL_ID' => 'Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID']);
    }

}
```

And finally Ayudante Model:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "ayudante".
 *
 * @property integer $Ayudante_ID
 * @property integer $Registro
 * @property string $Nombre
 *
 * @property AyudanteSituacionLaboral[] $ayudanteSituacionLaborals
 * @property SituacionLaboral[] $situacionLaboralSitLs
 * @property ViajeDistribucion[] $viajeDistribucions
 * @property ViajeGlp[] $viajeGlps
 */
class Ayudante extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'ayudante';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Registro','Nombre'],'required'],
            [['Registro'], 'integer'],
            [['CI'], 'string', 'max' => 11],
            [['Nombre'], 'string', 'max' => 50]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'Ayudante_ID' => 'ID',
            'Registro' => 'Registro',
            'CI'=>'CI',
            'Nombre' => 'Nombre',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAyudanteSituacionLaborals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AyudanteSituacionLaboral::className(), ['AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Ayudante_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSituacionLaboralSitLs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SituacionLaboral::className(), ['SitL_ID' => 'Situacion_LaboralSitL_ID'])->viaTable('ayudante_situacion_laboral', ['AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Ayudante_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getViajeDistribucions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ViajeDistribucion::className(), ['AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Ayudante_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getViajeGlps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ViajeGlp::className(), ['AyudanteAyudante_ID' => 'Ayudante_ID']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your problem. So, let's say we have a form that uses model `HRutaDistribucion`. If in `date` input we type something, it should check against which model? If the data of target model exists in database already?

Comment: Exactly. HRutaDistribucion form has two inputs> date and ayudante. So it must check both fields against AyudanteSituacionLaboral, I mean that in AyudanteSituacionLaboral doesn't exist a record with that Ayudante_ID in that date typed in form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you need  exist validator 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-existvalidator.html

In your  HRutaDistribucion  model you should add this to your rules

```
[['Date', 'Ayudante_ID '], 'exist',
       'targetClass' => AyudanteSituacionLaboral::ClassName() ,
        'targetAttribute' => ['Date', 'Ayudante_ID ']]
```

Comment: I put it like this:`return[[['Fecha', 'FechaEmision','Carro_DistribucionCarroID', 'ChoferChofer_ID', 'AyudanteAyudante_ID', 'HojaRuta','Capacidad_Transportada'], 'safe', 'on'=>'search'],[['Fecha', 'AyudanteAyudante_ID '], 'exist', 'targetClass' => AyudanteSituacionLaboral::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['FechaInicio', 'AyudanteAyudante_ID']]]; }` And I get this error. And I specified target attribute as FechaInicio that belongs to AyudanteSituacionLaboral.  `Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Getting unknown property: backend\models\HrutaDistribucion::FechaInicio`

Comment: you can look at my post in AyudanteSituacionLaboral model, attribbute FechaInicio

Comment: you have the attribute  in your rules  ..but you are sure that your have this asttribute in the db table related .. (I don't see it in the commented  list normally based  on the database table at the top)

Comment: Yes, this is the attribute. I updated the question, please check it.